# Get names of positional arguments from function's signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, signature

Using Python 3.x, I'm trying to get the name of all positional arguments from some function i.e:

```
def foo(a, b, c=1):
    return
```

Right now I'm doing this:

```
from inspect import signature, _empty
args =[x for x, p in signature(foo).parameters.items() if p.default == _empty]
```

When the function alows *args i.e:

```
def foo(a, b, c=1, *args):
    return
```

I'm adding the line:

```
args.remove("args")
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.

---

As [suggested by Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42352775/6076911) one better way to deal with *args case is using Parameter.kind:

```
from inspect import signature, Parameter
args =[]
for x, p in signature(foo).parameters.items():
    if p.default == Parameter.empty and p.kind != Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL:
        args.append(x)
```

Comment: Note that `args` is just some kind of "*agreement*": you can call the parameters whatever you want so there are definitely cases where this won't work.

Comment: Indeed, that's one of the reasons why I'm asking the question. Right now I'm using this for my own functions and I follow the args convention but I'm wondering how to achieve the same in a more "robust" way.

Comment: from inspect import signature, Parameter

this is very useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve a more robust solution by additionally checking if the [`.kind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter.kind) attribute of the parameter is not equal to `Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL`.

For `*args`, this is the value that is set when you build the signature object from a function:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c=1, *args): pass
>>> print(signature(foo).parameters['args'].kind)
VAR_POSITIONAL
```

So just import `Parameter` from `inspect` and add or the condition that `kind != Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL`:

```
>>> from inspect import Parameter
>>> Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL == p['args'].kind
True
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `.kind` instead of `._kind`? Attributes starting with an underscore are considered *private*.

Comment: Yes @WillemVanOnsem, quick typing gets the better of me sometimes.

Comment: Thanks! that solve the problem of *args. Although I still found the list comprehension a little ugly.

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia Packing everything in a one-liner often has the effect of resulting in an ugly one-liner. Refactoring it into a function with a loop is often a good idea.