# __kwdefaults__ is empty on python3 function with defined **kwargs

Tags: python-3.x

**python 3.6.8**

```
def xx(test=1, sim=0.2):
    return test + sim

print(xx.__defaults__, xx.__kwdefaults__)
```

**I get the following output:**

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Dec 29 2018, 10:04:55) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

Out[1]: (1, 0.2) None
```

**while I expect**

```
Out[1]: None {'test': 1, 'sim': 0.2}
```

**but then if I change**

```
def xx(*args, arg1, test=1, sim=0.2):
    return test + sim


print(xx.__defaults__, xx.__kwdefaults__)
```

**I get what I want:**

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Dec 29 2018, 10:04:55) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

Out[1]: None {'test': 1, 'sim': 0.2}
```

but my function by design should accept only keyword-type arguments, i.e. no `*args`.

## Why such behavior?

I need to obtain a list of arguments (name of the argument) and the default value of the keyword argument.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, `def xx(test=1, sim=0.2)` does accept `*` args. `def xx(*, test=1, sim=0.2)` won't though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my function is by design should accept only keyword-type arguments, i.e. no *args

Use `*` to say that explicitly, then you will get your desired output:

```
def foo(*, test=1): pass

print(foo.__kwdefaults__)
# {'test': 1}
```

`def foo(test=1)` does **not** make `test` a keyword-only argument. It just gives `test` a default value, but `test` can still be passed as a positional argument, ie `foo(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

`__kwdefaults__` applies only to arguments accepted *solely* by keyword; [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members):

> `__defaults__` - tuple of any default values for positional or keyword parameters
>   `__kwdefaults__` - mapping of any default values for keyword-only parameters

So if they *can* be passed positionally, they appear in `__defaults__`. If you want to make the arguments keyword-only without accepting positional arguments, add an empty `*` argument (new in Python 3; not available in Python 2):

```
def xx(*, test=1, sim=0.2):
    return test + sim
```

All arguments after the `*` can only be passed by keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__kwdefaults__), we see that `__kwdefaults__` is

> A dict containing defaults for keyword-only parameters.

Keyword-only arguments were introduced in [PEP3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/). In brief, they are any argument that follows either `*args` or a plain `*` in the [argument list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).

So while `test` and `sim` in `def xx(test=1, sim=0.2):` *may* be specified by keywords in an actual function invocation, they are in fact named positional arguments and not keyword-only.

One simple workaround would be to make them keyword-only using `*`:

```
def xx(*, test=1, sim=0.2):
```

If you need to get the defaults of named arguments, you can also do so with the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module:

```
from inspect import signature, Parameter

defaults = {p.name: p.default for p in signature(xx).parameters if p.default is not Parameter.empty}
```

<sup>Idea comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42352703/2988730).</sup>

The advantage of this solution is that it will report both positional and keyword defaults in one place. This way, you don't have to constrain your function to only accept keyword arguments.